# Need of proper concept of inverse function in sets

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

A function $X ∶ (\Omega_1, \{ \Omega_1 , \varnothing\}) \to (\Omega_2 , \{\Omega_2,A,A^c,\varnothing\})$ is given and $A$ is some non empty subset of $\Omega_2$. Now since I am new to measure theory a few doubts are haunting me.
 Can't we say that $X^{-1}(A)=∅$ since none of the elements of $F_1(F_1=\{ \Omega_1 , \varnothing\})$ are mapping to $A$ and then $X$ can be measurable? But the claim is that it is not measurable function. Please help.
Thanx!

Comment: "Thanx" is okay, but leave out things like "ASAP". Lots of people here dislike that. Patience is beautiful and invites more to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition: $$X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega\in\Omega_1\mid X(\omega)\in A\}$$
In words the preimage of set $A$ under function $X$.

So $X^{-1}(A)=\varnothing$ if and only if no elements of $\Omega_1$ are sent to an element in set $A$. Then consequently $X^{-1}(A^c)=\Omega_1$.

If that is the case then here $X$ is a measurable function because $X^{-1}(B)\in\{\Omega_1,\varnothing\}$ for each $B\in\{\Omega_2,A,A^c,\varnothing\}$

If $X^{-1}(A)=\Omega_1$ then $X^{-1}(A^c)=\varnothing$ and again we are dealing with a measurable function.

If $X^{-1}(A)\notin\{\varnothing,\Omega_1\}$ then the function is not measurable.

We cannot say that $X^{-1}(A)=\varnothing$ for the reason you give. To say anything useful on this we need more information about the function $X$.